# Xamarin Forms Collection with Multiple selection - limit number of selected items

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, collectionview

I need to limit number of selected items from my CollectionView.
Ex: I have a CollectionView with 20 items in list, but the user can only choose 5 out of 20. Is this possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It is **possible** . You can by [SelectableItemsView.SelectedItems Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.selectableitemsview.selecteditems?view=xamarin-forms#Xamarin_Forms_SelectableItemsView_SelectedItems) to know how much items be selected .

And invoking [SelectableItemsView.SelectionChanged Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.selectableitemsview.selectionchanged?view=xamarin-forms) to monitor its count as follow:

XML:

```
    <CollectionView x:Name="collectionView"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding Monkeys}"
                    SelectionMode="Multiple"
                    SelectionChanged="collectionView_SelectionChanged"
                    SelectedItems="{Binding SelectedMonkeys}">
        ...
    </CollectionView>
```

ContentPage:

```
private void collectionView_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("count is :" + collectionView.SelectedItems.Count);
    if(collectionView.SelectedItems.Count < 20 & collectionView.SelectedItems.Count >5)
    {
        // write code you want .
    }
}
```

Here is the offical [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/collectionview/selection) , and also has a official [sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/userinterface-collectionviewdemos/) for reference.

Comment: I had already tried it that way, the problem is that SelectionChangedEventArgs doesn't have an e.Cancel, for example. It needed to have an event that occurred before, like an OnSelectionChanging. But I did it another way, it's not ideal, but it resolves:

void OnCollectionViewSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (list.SelectedItems.Count > 5)
            {
                list.SelectedItems.Remove(list.SelectedItems[list.SelectedItems.Count - 1]);
            }
        }

Thanks!

Comment: @RicardoMiguel Glad solved ! Yeah more detail logic in program need to be designed . Okey, if my answer be helpful , you can vote it up. And you also can update your solution in answer to let other people know how to solve it *.^

Answer (score 0):

It's not ideal, but it resolves:

```
void OnCollectionViewSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e) {
   if (list.SelectedItems.Count > 5) 
   { 
      list.SelectedItems.Remove(list.SelectedItems[list.SelectedItems.Count - 1]); 
   } 
}
```

Comment: Gald sharing . Remember to mark your answer later and if my answer be helpful , thanks for voting up in advance.